# Ubuntu 16.10 Not able to delete files in mounted partition

Tags: partitioning, 16.10, mountpoint

In Ubuntu 16.10 I am not able to delete any file from mounted partition.I can only copy file from one mounted partition to others.I have tried by changing permission, mount point but not worked. Please provide solution

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running nautilus as root and deleting them?
Run the following command in the terminal (use Ctrl+Shift+T to open it):

`sudo nautilus`

Enter your password and attempt to delete them.

For future reference, always be wary when running nautilus as root. Things could be broken very easily.